# Animated .png files in javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, png

I'm writing a game, and I want to be able to animate some of my .png images. My world generator can place static images, is there a way to have javascript search the page for an image, and replace it with something else, or something similar to that?

Comment: Yes this is easily doable.  You can replace the `src` attribute on any img tag with javascript.  If you are going to need to do this extensively, you probably want to look at using a framework like jQuery to make it much easier to select and modify the tags you want to change.

Comment: @mike Tjhanks, I'll use that in other places. I never knew that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you ever heared about [APNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG)?

[image: Animated]

> is there a way to have javascript search the page for an image, and replace it with something else

Is very simple with jQuery:

```
$('img[src="http://foo.bar/image.jpg"]').attr('src', 'http://foo.bar/flower.jpg');
```

Comment: Do not use aPNG. I'm on the latest Chrome beta and it [doesn't work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG#Application_support).

Comment: I think I'll use that I'll need to get the Photoshop extention

Comment: @ColeJohnson Use this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ehkepjiconegkhpodgoaeamnpckdbblp

Comment: I understand there are extensions to use it. But it's best to support at least browsers from 2010. Heck, my school uses IE 6!

Comment: You better change the school :)

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski Sorry, but their stuck on XP because they claim a license for 7 would cost too much. Plus it would kill their IT guys :/ I managed to open Windows Update and found 100's (yes hundreds) of IMPORTANT updated that should be installed...

Comment: Back to the answer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG_animation using raster PNG's embeded right into it

Comment: APNGs would work perfectly, because the animation is not completely necessary. Just some eyecandy, and if it's not compadible, they show up static.